# Additional SD card remounts itself as read-only

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-2, external-sd

In my Galaxy SII there was everything ok for three years. All this time I used an external 64Gb SanDisk card.

Now after some uptime the card is remounted as RO. All the modifying operations on the card seem to be succeed but after reboot I see all the directories and files still there in an old state.

I didn't notice when this is happening exactly, but suspect that this behaviour appears after I run newly updated version of OsmAnd+.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been answered on [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/794650/microsd-transflash-card-loses-all-writes/935826#935826)

At some timepoint I asked similar question on both resources.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is some filesystem corruption on the SD card. Try scanning it with a filesystem checker on your PC (e.g. `fsck` under Linux).

Comment: No problems found in file system.